# How to check if the given Node is the root of a BST in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

As we knew, in a BST, the left nodes of the root must be smaller and the right nodes must be bigger than the root. We also knew that the node has `data`, `left`, and `right` attributes.
I need to define a function to check if the given root is the root of a BST or not. If it's a BST, the function must return `True` and if not, `False`.

This is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data) -> None:
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def is_bst(root: Node):
        if root is None or (root.left is None and root.right is None):
            return True
        elif root.right is None:
            return root.left.data < root.data and is_bst(root.left)
        elif root.left is None:
            return root.right.data > root.data and is_bst(root.right)

    return is_bst(root.left) and is_bst(root.right)

a = Node(2)
a.left = Node(4)
a.right = Node(1)
print(is_bst(a))
```

You can see I did make a tree that is not BST but it returns `True` anyway...

Comment: In your example you execute the return is_bst(root.left) and is_bst(root.right) for the root and than only the if root is None or (root.left is None and root.right is None) for both right and left... where did you check that root > left and root < right in case both are not None ? you don't...

Comment: @yehudahs Thank you for paying attention. I know where my problem is but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I suggest rewrite `__init__` to allow children as arguments. For instance, `def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None): self.data = data; self.left = left; self.right = right`. This way, you can build a tree directly by writing `a = Node(2, Node(4), Node(1))`.

Comment: An obvious mistake in your code is that the last line, `return is_bst(root.left) and is_bst(root.right)`, is not correctly indented.

Answer (score 1):

change the is_bst to:

```
def is_bst(root):
    # stop condition
    if root is None:
        return True

    # check left < root
    if root.left is not None:
        if root.data <= root.left.data:
            return False

    #check right > root
    if root.right is not None:
        if root.data >= root.right.data:
            return False

    # continue checking recursivly.
    return is_bst(root.left) and is_bst(root.right)
```

personally, I rather not deal with it and just use some open-source framework (like networkx)... it has a bunch of helper functions that you can query your data structures...

Comment: Thank you. It's obviously better than mine but still has a bug for equal numbers.

Comment: does BST root need to be bigger than the left OR can it be also equal ? if it can be equal than the solution should be fine... if not, than you should add >= or <= instead of > and < respectly.

Comment: The root must be bigger than the left nodes and smaller than the right nodes.

Comment: I fixed the answer... added >= or <= instead of > and <

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to check `root.left.data < root.data < root.right.data` when neither of the children is `None`.

I also suggest adding optional argument for children in method `__init__`, so that you can define a tree more easily.

Note that `is_bst` is a method of class `Node`. You called its first argument `root`, but we typically like to call the first argument of a method `self`. For instance, `Node.is_bst(root.left)` is equivalent to `root.left.is_bst()`.

You don't really need to specify `root: Node`; of course `root` is of type `Node`; the first argument of at method of a class is always an object of that class.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def is_bst(root):
        if root is None or (root.left is None and root.right is None):
            return True
        elif root.right is None:
            return root.left.data < root.data and root.left.is_bst()
        elif root.left is None:
            return root.right.data > root.data and root.right.is_bst()
        else:
            return (
                root.left.data < root.data < root.right.data
                and root.left.is_bst()
                and root.right.is_bst()
            )

a = Node(2, Node(4), Node(1))
b = Node(2, Node(1), Node(4))

print('a is a bst? ', a.is_bst())
# a is a bst?  False

print('b is a bst? ', b.is_bst())
# b is a bst?  True
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a tree like this [10 6 20 4 50 12 21]. Then it'll show that it's BST but the truth is that it's not!!
To check for BST perform in order traversal store it in some list. Then check whether the list is in increasing order or not. In this case the inorder traversal will give [4 6 50 10 12 20 21] thus not a BST. Code:

```
class check_BST:
    def isValidBST(self, root):
        output = []
        self.inorder(root, output)
        for i in range(1,len(output)):
            if output[i-1] >= output[i]:
                return False
        
        return True
    
    def inorder(self, root, out):
        if root is not None:
            self.inorder(root.left, out)
            out.append(root.val)
            self.inorder(root.right, out)
        else:
            return
```